# Using an asp:LinkButton inside an asp:Image

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I've searched and haven't found this exact issue yet.  I am trying to place a hyperlink inside a Bootstrap Popover.  If it were just a static link I see how to do that.  However, this is a server side linkbutton.  Below is what I am trying to accomplish.  Obviously I cannot use an ASP control inside another control.  Is there a way I can create the link in codebehind and pass into the asp:image or is there a way to put the linkbutton in a hidden div and use that as the popover's data-content?

```
<asp:Image ID="disp_icon" runat="server" data-toggle="popover" 
  data-html="true" ImageUrl="~/images/ico_info.png" 
  ToolTip="Discipline" data-content="You may contact us 
  at 555.555.5555 or use the <asp:LinkButton ID="requestHistory_LinkButton" 
  runat="server" OnClick="showRequestHistoryForm_LinkButton_Click">
  history form</asp:LinkButton> to confirm the entire public record." />
```

**Attempt 1:**

I am trying this and as all the samples out there show, it should work:

```
        $(".discipline_icon").popover({
            title: function () {
                return $('.disciplineIconContent').html();
            },
            content: function () {
                return $('.disciplineIconContent').html();
            }
        });
        alert($('.disciplineIconContent').html());
```

...

```
<div class="disciplineIconContent" style="display:none;">You may contact the State Bar of Arizona at 602.340.7384 or use the <asp:LinkButton ID="requestHistory_LinkButton9" runat="server" CssClass="lawyerURL" OnClick="showRequestHistoryForm_LinkButton_Click" Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True">lawyer history form</asp:LinkButton> to confirm the lawyer's entire public record.</div>
```

The alert shows I am getting the contents of the div correctly.  But for some reason even though I assign it to the content, it never shows up.

Answer (score 0):

You have to let the link think its static and call some code behind code that will determine what the URL is instead.

eg.

```
    <a href='<% GetLinkURL() %>'>History Form</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right; you cannot place LinkButton inside data-content. However, you can trigger LinkButton's Click Event manually. It is a kind of hack.

Example,

```
<asp:Image ID="disp_icon" runat="server"
    data-html="true"
    data-toggle="hover"
    ImageUrl="~/images/ico_info.png"
    ToolTip="Discipline"
    data-content="You may contact us at 555.555.5555 or use the <a id='linkRequestHistory' onclick='postHistoryForm();'> history form</a> to confirm the entire public record." />

<asp:LinkButton ID="requestHistory_LinkButton"
    runat="server" OnClick="showRequestHistoryForm_LinkButton_Click" CssClass="hidden">
</asp:LinkButton>

<style type="text/css">
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#<%= disp_icon.ClientID %>").popover();

    function postHistoryForm() {
        __doPostBack("<%= requestHistory_LinkButton.ClientID %>", "");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Seems like this should work but no matter where I put the postHistoryForm script, I get postHistoryForm is undefined when I click the link.

Comment: Do you see `postHistoryForm` function when you view source inside the browser?

Comment: I do. I can see the function.  Tried placing it right before the image and linkbutton, right after, even at the top of the page.  Makes no sense why it can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I appear to have a working solution.  I think I was having an issue with the popup being created or initialized twice.  I removed the data-toggle="popover" for this specific element since I attach to it separately.  I can then place my HTML inside a hidden div.

```
        $('.discipline_icon').popover({
            placement: "auto",
            trigger: "hover click focus",
            html: true,
            title: "Discipline",
            content: $(".disciplineIconContent").html()
        })
```

. . .

```
<div class="disciplineIconContent hidden">
    You may contact us at 555.555.5555 or use the 
    <asp:LinkButton ID="requestHistory_LinkButton" runat="server" 
      OnClick="showRequestHistoryForm_LinkButton_Click">history form</asp:LinkButton> 
    to confirm the entire public record.</div>
```